# How to figure out TM and TE modes based on dispersion relation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization, dispersion, optical-materials

According to this paper (https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5128679), the dispersion relation of hyperbolic materials is as follows:

[image]

then it is said, that he first term in brackets in the equation describes a TE polarized wave while the second brackets represents TE modes. I'm having a really hard time understanding this. Is there anyway to  deduce polarization modes from dispersion relation? Any help would be highly appreciated.